# few windows of one app opened how to make active one particular by one click? (Mac OS X 10.6.2)

Tags: macos, mac

I have to use Mac in my work from yesterday and I'd like to know how can I make active one particular window if I have opened let's say 3 firefox windows or 3 terminal windows by **one mouse click**. Is there any way I can have list of all way available open applications and its windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Mark's answer, with one mouse click you can also left-click and hold the application icon in the dock, and it will lay out the windows associated with that application using Exposé. Then you can select the window you want.

Comment: I find that really not ergonomic at all ...

Comment: not ergonomic in my opinion but the best available ...

Answer (score 1):

If you cmd (or right click) on the the app in the dock you get a list of the apps windows to choose.

There is also a third party app [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) that gives a list of windows to select

Comment: I do like the right click. I wish there will be available list of all apps windows of all running applications at all times somewhere on the screen

Comment: Witch will provide that list

Comment: I didn't get this comment ....

Comment: The application Witch does provide a list of all windows of running applications